# Onkeyup is not working

Tags: javascript, onkeyup

Although I can see an "onkeyup" event in the chrome console, for whatever reason, the event is not firing.

```js
var el = document.getElementById("userInput");
el.addEventListener("onkeyup", function() {
    alert('yahoooo0');
});
```

```html
<input type="text" id="userInput" name="food"/>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Update your `event listener` from `onkeyup` to `keyup`.

```js
var el = document.getElementById("userInput");
el.addEventListener("keyup", function() {
    alert('yahoooo0');
});
```

```html
<input type="text" id="userInput" name="food"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
el.addEventListener("keyup", function() {
```

Answer (score 0):

try this :

```
$("#userInput").keyup(function() {
   alert('yahoooo0');
});
```

[test on fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/n3fmw1mw/)

Comment: The question is not tagged with `Jquery`

Answer (score 0):

You can change the eventlistener name from `onkeyup` to `keyup` or you may use below simple eventlistenter attaching method

```
<input type="text" id="userInput" name="food" onkeyup="doSomething()"/>
```